# How can i recieve an object of class, when i'm click on ListView Item?

Tags: java, android, class, listview, object

I have one class, where some number of **fields** are located.

```
public class Equipment {
    public String GlobalType;
    public String NameEquip;
    public String SerialNumEquip;
    public String EquipmentMark;
    public String IDequipment;
    public String StatusEquipment;
    public String InstDate;
    public String StateEquipment;
    public String GurEndDate;
    public String Location;}
```

In `ListView` I am using three of these fields I have **custom layout for three** `TextView`s, but, when I click on one item, I need to receive an object of class, whose **fields** I am using in `ListView`.

Comment: setOnClicklisteners to specific textViews or if its long string then use spannable onclicks.

Comment: Can you show how to set setOnClickListener to textview?

Comment: To all the TextView i meant

Answer (score 1):

Here is it:

```
getList().setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Object object = parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            // And then cast object to your type
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, you to read [information](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html) about Adapter for ListView/RecyclerView/ViewHolder pattern in Android - it is basics of the Android. After that, you can easily to do it.

Comment: I've read, but still don't get it. I am new to java and android, so can you explain it to me?

Comment: You need to create your own adapter, which will simplify your interaction with every single element of your list. Just repeat the [example](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html?hl=en#Example)

Answer (score 0):

Use `interface` as `Callback` inside your `Adapter` and Handle at Your `Activity` Or `Fragment`

```
// ++++++++++ Inside Adapter
private OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener;
public interface OnItemClickListener {
    void onClicked(int viewId, int position, Object item);
}
// OnBinde / OnView
if (onItemClickListener != null) {
    onItemClickListener.onClicked(myTappedView.getId(), getAdapterPosition(), item);
}
// ++++++++++ Inside Activity / Fragment
public void onClicked(int viewId, int position, Object item) {
    if (item instanceof MyCustomObject) {
        // Do Some Things
    }
}
```